# Python Reading File and Skipping Invalid Lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I've been trying to write some code to read a CSV file. Some of the lines in the CSV are not complete. I would like the code to skip a bad line if there is data missing in one of the fields. I'm using the following code.

```
def Test():

    dataFile = open('test.txt','r')
    readFile = dataFile.read()
    lineSplit = readFile.split('\n')

    for everyLine in lineSplit:
        dividedLine = everyLine.split(';')
        a = dividedLine[0]
        b = dividedLine[1]
        c = dividedLine[2]
        d = dividedLine[3]
        e = dividedLine[4]
        f = dividedLine[5]
        g = dividedLine[6]

        print (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
```

Comment: Nitpick: a `;`-delimited dataset isn't a CSV.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the *Pythonic* way to do this would be to use the included `csv` module in conjunction with a `try/except` block (while following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

```
import csv

def test():
    with open('reading_test.txt','rb') as data_file:
        for line in csv.reader(data_file):
            try:
                a,b,c,d,e,f,g = line
            except ValueError:
                continue  # ignore the line
            print(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)

test()
```

This approach is called "It's Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission" (EAFP). The other more common style is referred to as "Look Before You Leap" (LBYL). You can read more about them in [this snippet](https://books.google.com/books?id=JnR9hQA3SncC&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=%22lbyl%22+%22python%22&source=bl&ots=Jc2UNrW67x&sig=gZ1ttM1VLBpFd8g5QYJipW5yExw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lbtGVMWKBcqfyAS804GgBw&ved=0CGQQ6AEwCg#v=onepage&q=%22lbyl%22%20%22python%22&f=false) from a book by a very authoritative author.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you cannot know before hand whether a given line is incomplete, you need to check if it is and skip it if it is not. You can use `continue` for this, which makes the `for` loop move to the next iteration:

```
def Test():

    dataFile = open('test.txt','r')
    readFile = dataFile.read()
    lineSplit = readFile.split('\n')

    for everyLine in lineSplit:
        dividedLine = everyLine.split(';')

        if len(dividedLine) != 7:
            continue

        a = dividedLine[0]
        b = dividedLine[1]
        c = dividedLine[2]
        d = dividedLine[3]
        e = dividedLine[4]
        f = dividedLine[5]
        g = dividedLine[6]

        print (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem all-that python related so much as conceptual: A line parsed from a csv row will be invalid if:
1. It is shorter than the minimum required length (i.e missing elements)
2. One or more entries parsed come back empty or None (only if all elements are required)
3. The type of an element doesn't match the intended type of the column (not in the scope of what you requested, but good to keep in mind)

In python, once you have split the array, you can check the first two conditions with

```
if len(dividedLines) < intended_length or ("" in dividedLines): continue
```

First part just needs you to get the intended length for a row, you can usually use the index row for that. The second part could have the quotes replaced with a None or something, but split returns a empty string so in this case use the "".

HTH

Comment: Over time I have found the problem with this approach, which is called "Look Before You Leap" (LBYL), is there's often a huge (infinite?) number of ways to do something wrong, verses a much smaller number of right ways. Rather than try to think of, and write code to handle all of these possibilities (assuming it's even possible), it's often much easier to just attempt to perform the operation and see if can be completed without any problems.